# Outlook add in cannot reset Bcc field

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am currently struggling with the situation that I cannot remove the bcc value, when trying to set it to an empty array, empty string or null this will throw an error.

```
return item['bcc'].setAsync([], (asyncResult) => {
  if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    return failure(Error(asyncResult.error.message))
  }

  return success()
})
```

I couldn't find a way in the documentation something like a removeAsync maybe? Is there another solution to remove the value from Bcc field?

Client: Outlook for Mac
Version: 16.46 (21021202)

Error message when Bcc is set to empty array:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): An internal error has occurred.
```

Error message when Bcc is set to empty string or null:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Sys.ArgumentException): Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Parameter name: recipients

Comment: Are you using the web client inside a browser, or the rich native desktop client (in Windows or Mac) or are you using a mobile app? Also, what is the error message or exception? Can you provide your version number of Outlook as well if you are using the rich native desktop client?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Sorry that I forgot to mention that from the beginning, I've made an update with the error messages and versions.

Comment: We are also experiencing this as well with the "New Outlook" desktop app on Mac. It works on the "current outlook" desktop app on mac and web version is fine.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. We can repro this on new mac Outlook UI. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point.